# How i can change the Access point on Lumia 630?

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-630

In lumia 720 (my previous phone) it's possible to change the access point.

Now I need change the access point on my new device (a Lumia 630) but I can not find where to do it on the settings. It's possible to create and switch between access points in lumia 630?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by access point? Do you mean the APN settings for the cellular connection?

Comment: `Access Point` is an application to manage individual operator settings for internet, `MMS` and internet sharing features. In `Lumia 720` this app is already included but I can't find/download it for `Lumia 630`.

Comment: Are you using WP 8 or 8.1, and who's your carrier?

Comment: I'm using 8.1. What's "carrier" mean?

Comment: carrier = mobile phone network

Answer (score 1):

Download one of these apps on your lumia 630
Lumia System Updater
SysApp Pusher

Scroll through the list and find Access Point click on it and it will take you to the store , install the app if not installed already , if it says installed and if you cannot find it in the settings then im afraid your operator must have blocked it for some reason.

Try changing your sim+operator and then find the app in settings , even then you cannot find it there are two possible reasons

- Microsoft itself has blocked that app in your region , so try changing the region to US and then look for the app.
- Even after changing the region you cannot find the app then it means Lumia 630 does not have this feature (if your model is a dual Sim it must have Access point in the settings search properly)

Final option reset your phone and update to the developer preview everything gets unlocked for you.

Hope i helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft made APN settings a little harder to find in WP8.1 than they were before, but they are still there. Some carriers might be able to block you from accessing them, but in general these are the steps:

1. Open `Settings`, then `cellular+SIM`.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page, and open `SIM settings`.
3. Toggle the "Manual Internet APN" option to on, if you need to set the Internet APN.
4. Enter your APN settings, then hit Save (the diskette icon in the app bar at the bottom).
5. If you want to set a custom MMS APN, go back to the "SIM" settings page.
6. Tap `Add MMS APN` (at the bottom of the page) and enter your MMS APN settings.